# Understanding Terminology in Goodfellow's paper on GANS

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to understand Ian Goodfellow et al's paper Generative Adversarial Nets [here](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets.pdf).

In section 3 the author's write:

> The adversarial modeling framework is most straightforward to apply
>   when the models are both multilayer perceptrons. To learn the
>   generator’s distribution $p_g$ over data $x$, we define a prior on input
>   noise variables $p_z(z)$, then represent a mapping to data space as $G(z;
> $ $\theta_g)$, where $G$ is a differentiable function represented by a multilayer
>   perceptron with parameters $\theta_g$.

I have a few questions.

1) From what I understand, the generator is a multi-layer perceptron input with a random vector sampled from a predefined latent space, (where wikipedia gives the example of a multivariate normal distribution). What does it mean to learn the generator's distribution $p_g$ over data $x$?

2) What does "we define a prior on input noise variables $p_z(z)$" mean? I understand that in Bayesian statistical inference, that a prior probability distribution, called a prior for short, gives a probability distribution on outcomes before some evidence is collected.

Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**

> 1) From what I understand, the generator is a multi-layer perceptron input with a random vector sampled from a predefined latent space, (where wikipedia gives the example of a multivariate normal distribution). What does it mean to learn the generator's distribution $p_g$ over data x?

Generally, supervised learning means to learn a distribution $p_{model}(y\mid x)$ where $x$ are your examples and $y$ your labels. However, in unsupervised learning it is not about labels but instead you are interested in unconditional probabilities and train a model to learn $p_{model}(x)$ (e.g. see p.485/486 in "The Elements of Statistical Learning" by Hastie et al). When applying GANs this $model$ is the generator $g$, i.e. you are learning $p_{g}(x)$. Accordingly, in [the original paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets.pdf) the authors state:

> The generator $G$ implicitly defines a probability distribution $p_g$ as the distribution of the samples $G(z)$ obtained when $z ∼ p_z$.

---

**Question 2**

> 2) What does "we define a prior on input noise variables $p_z(z)$" mean? I understand that in Bayesian statistical inference, that a prior probability distribution, called a prior for short, gives a probability distribution on outcomes before some evidence is collected.

Prior means we are talking unconditional probabilities, i.e. $p(z)$ is not conditioned on anything related to the task and examples on hand. While for example, $p_d(y\mid x)$ (the distribution learned by the Discriminator) is conditioned on $x$. Often $z$ is sampled from the standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

In ["NIPS 2016 Tutorial: Generative Adversarial Networks"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.00160) the authors provide a good summary of the overall concept of $G$:

> The generator is simply a differentiable function $G$. When
>   $z$ is sampled from some simple prior distribution, $G(z)$ yields a sample of $x$
>   drawn from $p_{model}$. Typically, a deep neural network is used to represent $G$.

Comment: When the authors write : " To learn the generator’s distribution $p_g(x)$", do they mean for any set of parameters or for a fixed set of parameters? Because this seems if it is the latter, that we are learning a family of probability distributions for each $\theta_g$?

Comment: @IntegrateThis $p_g(x)$ does not depend on $\theta$. Only $G$ does. So I'd say you are learning $p_g(x)$ by training $G(z_g;\theta_g)$ so $G(z_g;\theta_g)$ produces samples drawn from $p_g(x)$.